# jQuery remove specific value on textbox by specific id click

Tags: jquery

I have this value on textbox.

JS to get the product name

```
$('#imageInputCurrent').val(jsonStr.productImage);
```

-

```
<input type="text" id="imageInputCurrent" value="PRD_62533.jpg,PRD_63335.jpg,PRD_48298.jpg,PRD_89675.jpg,PRD_30890.jpg"/>
```

And Now I have remove button for each product.

[image]

So when I try to click one of remove image, it will remove the value to textbox `id="productImage`.

Example, I click remove button `PRD_62533.jpg` so it will take out from the textbox.

Here is the JS:

```
$('.removeImageInput').on('click', function()
{
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');

    $('.subImageListInput'+ID).hide();
});
```

So my question how to remove the current click remove image product name value from textbox `imageInputCurrent` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work :

```
$('.removeImageInput').on('click',function(){
    var pic = "PRD_62533.jpg"; // assume you can get pic's full name

    var value = $('#imageInputCurrent').val();
    var index = value.indexOf(pic);

    // if there is a comma right after pic string in value
    // add a comma after the string that gonna to be replaced
    // or add a comma behind it
    // var replace = value[index+pic.length] == ',' ? pic + ',' : ',' + pic;
    var replace = value[index+pic.length] == ',' ? pic + ',' : value[index-1] == ',' ? ',' + pic : pic;
    value = value.replace(replace, '');
    console.log(value);
    $('#imageInputCurrent').val(value);
})
```

Edit: Just right after posting, I found that this won't work if there's only one jpg in `$('#imageInputCurrent').val()`

Ryuk Lee's answer would be a better choice

Edit2: Now it works fine even if there's only one jpg.

Comment: Thanks. `This won't work if there's only one jpg  in $('#imageInputCurrent').val()` I also think about it ^^

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.removeImageInput').on('click', function(){
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    var a = $('#imageInputCurrent').val().split(',');
    if(a.indexOf(ID) != -1){
        a.splice(a.indexOf(ID), 1);
    }
    $('#imageInputCurrent').val(a.toString());
    $('.subImageListInput'+ID).hide();
});
```

Edit : Now it works fine even if there are many ID in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="imageInputCurrent" value="PRD_62533.jpg,PRD_63335.jpg,PRD_48298.jpg,PRD_89675.jpg,PRD_30890.jpg"/>

<input type="button" class="removeImageInput" value="Remove" data-value="PRD_62533.jpg"/>
<input type="button" class="removeImageInput" value="Remove" data-value="PRD_63335.jpg"/>

<script>
$('.removeImageInput').on('click', function(){

    var image_list = $("#imageInputCurrent").val();
    var remove_image = $(this).attr('data-value');

    var updated_image_list="";
    if(image_list!=null){

        updated_image_list=image_list.replace(remove_image+',','');
        updated_image_list=updated_image_list.replace(','+remove_image,'');
        updated_image_list=updated_image_list.replace(remove_image,'');

        console.log(updated_image_list);
    }
});
```